# Call and Chat in MS Teams from Bot Framework

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I would like to know if is possible to run a Call with someone else in Microsoft Teams from the BotFramework. Specifically I have an adaptive card where I want to perform this action. Then MSTeams client should open the call with the person I want. Is there a way for that. Same thing would be great for chatting.